# The continuative and non-continuative readings of the perfect form (have + past participle)

Tags: perfect-aspect

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Page 141) has this section:
[image]

Here, **Tr** is the time referred to (by the verb or verb group, e.g., *have told*, *have been*, *told*, *was*), and **To** is the time of orientation, which equates to the time of utterance in this question.

Now, my question is about the distinction made in the quoted portion of CGEL between the **continuative** and **non-continuative** readings of the perfect. If I understand it correctly, CGEL is making the distiction that the perfect locates Tr "before and up to To" and "wholly before To" in the **continuative** and **non-continuative** reading, respectively.

The following perfect in bold I think has the continuative reading:

> (1) She **has been writing** the book since she was in her twenties and at last it's finished.

But here, Tr, the time referred to by the verb group **has been writing**, doesn't seem to extend up to the time of utterance (To), because at the time of uttrance, she's not longer writing the book.

Am I misunderstanding CGEL or is CGEL's distinction between the **continuative** and **non-continuative** reading of the perfect doesn't really apply to example (1)?

### EDIT

Here's some evidence supporting CGEL's claim that the continuative reading's Tr includes To:

A 2002 linguistics paper titled "[Event Structure and the Perfect - Stanford University](https://web.stanford.edu/~kiparsky/Papers/semanticsfest.pdf)" by Paul Kiparsky (page 5) quotes another paper (Mittwoch 1988) to say this:

> The universal reading requires an adverb specifying a duration (such as
>   *always*, *since 1960* or *for two years*)...
>
> [T]he boundaries that define the duration are understood in an exclusive way in the existential reading but in an inclusive way in the universal reading (Mittwoch 1988). The sentence
>
> [10] I have been in Hyderabad since 1977.
>
> is false on the existential reading if I last was in Hyderabad in 1977 or if I
>   have just landed on my first visit there; it is the intervening time that counts
>   (exclusive boundaries). For the universal reading of [10] to be true I must
>   have been there in 1977 and **I must be there now** (inclusive boundaries).

(Boldface mine.)
(Here, the existential reading refers to the experiential reading, whereas the universal reading refers to the continuative reading.)

So what this paper is saying is that the continuative reading must include the boundaries that define the duration specified by an adverb (e.g., since 1977).

Since this 2002 paper by a reputable linguist quotes a 1988 paper to make this point, I highly doubt that this specific claim made by this paper is questionable. Moreover, this paper's claim is in line with CGEL' explanation that the continuative reading's Tr includes To.

Comment: Looks to me as though you are ignoring their definition of continuative / non-continutative, which does not say that a continuous / progressive perfect has to have the continuative reading. If you think that, in your sentence, Tr includes the time of utterance, why call it continuative?

Comment: @Minty You're right. They didn't say that a progressive perfect has to have the continuative reading. But I didn't say they did, either. I think of (1)'s **has been writing** as the continuative perfect, not merely because it's the progressive perfect, but because it does have the continuative reading as I know it. (Please let me know if you think (1)'s **has been writing** is the non-continuative perfect.) And I'm sure that CGEL's distinction between the two readings is supposed to apply to the progressive perfect as well as the non-progressive perfect.

Comment: It seems to me that *careful around the woodwork, I’ve been painting* is fine, but *careful around the woodwork, I’ve been painting since 5 am* is questionable. If that’s right, I think the explanation is that *since* forces the continuative meaning, which would mean that (1) is continuative, as you say. OTOH what makes the second sentence sound odd could be that my early start has no bearing on the warning I am giving.

Comment: Is there a difference between *those neighbours have been annoying me for 5 years, and at last they’re gone* and *those annoying people have been there for 5 years, and at last they’re gone*, or is it just me? If there is a difference, I think it has a bearing on how (1) should be accounted for.

Comment: @Minty I'm not sure what you're trying to say with your own examples. Why not just discuss the given example? If you're wondering, though, CGEL says _since_ doesn't force the continuative reading, only _ever since_ does.

Comment: I think they have a bearing on how (1) should be accounted for. An explanation that only works for one sentence is not much use - it needs to be generalisable.

Comment: @Minty I think this question is already hard enough to answer with the specific example, (1). Is my question not clear enough as it is?

Comment: There are several possible analyses and I don’t think you can choose between them based on a single sentence. One is that (1) presents the activity of writing a book as continuing at the time of the utterance (I think *writing a book* can include dealing with editors, publishers, etc., but you can say *it’s finished* as soon as the actual writing is done). You can test that by looking at other dynamic verbs. Another is that for the present progressive, the continuative / non-continuative distinction is between time periods which abut t0 and time periods which do not...

Comment: ... but I think this may only apply to dynamic verbs, so you would have to consider some examples of stative verbs. If you want to explore the question in any meaningful way, you will have to look at other examples.

Comment: @Minty Firstly, your first analysis is not what I intended for example (1). It's not about dealing with editors or publishers, it's about just writing the book. You can certainly say (1) in this sense. I don't understand your second analysis. I'd like to make it clear that this is not a question about the present perfect progressive in general; it's a question about the specific example provided in the question.

Comment: I think you're equating two different tenses/aspects. I think this is because the same verbs are used to create the tense/aspect in the past perfect and what you have in your example. "He may (have been) here..." - (have been) present perfect / "She has been writing the book..." - (has been writing) should, I think be seen as something other than the present perfect as a whole. I mean "has been" shouldn't be seen separately from "has been writing", which can be referred to as the present past continuous or present past progressive. That's how I see it, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Just thinking about this more, notice how in the CGEL example the present perfect isn't followed by the present participle, whereas in your example it is? Maybe this is a difference, in other words, as I said, it's often called the past perfect continuous or past perfect progressive because it combines the past perfect with the progressive or continuous use of the present participle, ie., (... has been writing...), not "has been here...."

Comment: @Zebrafish Sorry, but your analysis is not in line with CGEL's description of the perfect tense. CGEL doesn't treat the perfect progressive form as a non-perfect form. So, no, there's no way this issue can be resolved with your analysis.

Comment: If you're going to adhere to the prescriptions of CGEL, then saying "I've been writing a book since I was ..." and you are still writing the book, then if 1) CGEL doesn't allow that form as a non-perfect tense, and 2) sounds as if you are still writing the book, then I'd suggest the description in CGEL isn't an exhaustive one of how English is spoken in real life. Also note, that it's not obvious whether you intend a perfect or imperfect tense in that sentence until you add "and at last it's finished." So the the tense itself, I'd argue cannot be deduced solely from "has been writing".

Comment: In other words, "I've been writing a book since I was 15, and I have finally finished it" and "I've been writing a book since I was 15; it's almost finished" both sound like fine English to me (and you presumably), but you say that CGEL treats "I've been writing" as a non-perfect tense, then I'm inclined to believe that, as I said before, its descriptions aren't exhaustive of how the language is spoken in real life. I find this isn't uncommon with grammars or style guides, there always seem to be exceptions. Of course, if you want to assert that CGEL is infallible, then there's a discrepancy.

Comment: @Zebrafish Please note that I said, "CGEL **doesn't** treat the perfect progressive form as a non-perfect form."

Comment: OK, so "She has been writing the book since she was in her twenties..." by itself is taken to mean present perfect continuous (or progressive), and is perfect (at least that's how I see it.) However you can either add ", and has finally finished it" to mean a perfect tense, or ", and will finish it soon" to mean imperfect tense, right? In that case it seems to me that it can be treated as both, and specified by the extra information provided. I've noticed in the CGEL examples it doesn't mention anything about the event ending, but in your example sentence it does: "and at last it's finished."

Comment: @JK2: Are you asking: "can the continuative perfect extend to immediately before the time of speaking, but not actually include it?" I think the answer is "yes' and the CGEL is being careless in its explanation, although maybe they mean to define continuative so the answer is "no". But if that's what you're asking, it would be good to be more explicit; it took me a while to figure out your question.

Comment: Is there a section in this CGEL reference that refers specifically to present perfect progressive?  Because from my reading of your question, present perfect progressive will always fall into the "continuative" group.

Comment: I think Peter Shor has the right answer. The definition of continuative as you give it is 'Tr before and up to To'. 'Up to' could also be interpreted as up to but not including the exact moment of utterance. A related way of looking at it is to think of To as an extended present  such as today, this week, e.g. I've been smoking for 25 years, but today I gave up cigarettes.

Comment: @PeterShor Sorry, but I don't understand why you're suggesting CGEL is simply being careless. The quoted portion explicitly states at the outset "...extending forward to include To". Moreover, [ib] means "it's possible that he has been here ever since," which I think clearly indicates that the situation of him being here extends forward to include To. Now returning to your first question, I think you can certainly say (1) even the day after she finished writing the book. No?

Comment: @Karlomanio I don't think there's such a section. But the question is why (1) doesn't  seem to fall into the continuative group.

Comment: @SConroy CGEL's wording is such that "up to" does include the moment of utterance. Otherwise, they wouldn't have defined the "non-continuative" as "Tr wholly before To".

Comment: If she finished the book yesterday, couldn't you say *"She was writing the book for years, and at last it's finished"*? So the preterite is excluded only if you define "continuative" as including *"To"*, which may be why CGEL has defined "continuative" in this way.

Comment: @PeterShor "She was writing the book for years, and at last it's finished" does work for me if she finished the book yesterday. So maybe "has been" in "She has been writing the book for years, and at last it's finished" is the non-continuative reading in CGEL's analysis, but it still can convey **a continuous reading** solely due to the continuous aspect "be + writing"??

Comment: I think it still works with the CGEL definition if you see To as today/this week etc. Tr is then wholly before today/this week.

Comment: @SConroy No. As I have said in the question, To is the time of utterance. It's the exact moment of speaking, not some period of time such as 'today' or 'this week'.

Comment: My understanding is different (unless you have other info that is not provided in the question) and I tried to explain why in the last comment.

Comment: @SConroy Please see the EDIT for more evidence.

Comment: @PeterShor Please see the EDIT.

Comment: That extra info just muddies the water for me. If it were a more precise definition from CGEL itself, it would help. If someone says: "You look exhaused!" And your answer is "I have been running", you won't be running at the exact moment of utterance. The effects, though, reach into the moment of utterance. I'm not going to convince you, so will leave it at the that.

Comment: I agree with @SConroy.  I'd like to edit my answer, but I'm not sure exactly what you are saying.  It seems to me.  Yes, you have a point.  It depends on where you are or what you are doing at that point.

Comment: (1) 'She has been writing the book since she was in her twenties and at last it's finished' switches from a _Tr includes To_ stance to a _Tr has ended before To_ stance as one moves from one independent clause to the other. It's clumsy, but I'd say idiomatic enough to be considered acceptable grammar. Like switching to the historic present mid-dialogue. I'd probably use separate sentences.

Answer (score 1):

The time of the utterance is confined to the clause in which the tense is used.  "and *now* it's finished" or "and *at last*..." establishes a new time-reference in a separate clause.

Consider:

> I've been looking forward to this birthday dinner all week. It's delicious.

After the meal is *over*, you wouldn't use the present perfect:

> That was delicious. I'd been looking forward to it all week.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance if we talk about the example you are giving, this could be interpreted as a non-continuative action

> She has been writing the book since she was in her twenties

This sounds to my ear more the exception than the rule.  I would never have thought of this example, had you not have brought it up.

Your point is well-taken. This excerpt from Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL) has not taken into account times when the present perfect progressive could express an action that is not continuative, ie. **T**r **wholly before T**o.

Comment: Okay, then. Could you just forget example (1) for the moment and consider a context where she has just finished writing the book? In that context, consider example (1') _She has been writing the book since she was in her twenties._ This example is "an independent clause," but it can be uttered even after the book is finished. I see no difference between (1) and (1') as long as both are uttered after the book's finished.

Comment: You might be right. But the problem is, all the grammars and linguistic papers that I know of classify example (1) as an instance of the continuative/universal reading of the perfect.

Comment: So you're also looking for a reference to justify or not justify your reading?

Comment: Of course, I'd need some evidence, if I were to treat (1) as the non-continuative perfect.

Comment: What kind of evidence were you looking for?  I understand the need for evidence, but what if the source of evidence is incorrect?  What if someone needs to write a new thesis paper to justify that this is so?